# Showing sum of reciprocals of primes less than $2^{100}$ is less than $8$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is: 
Let $P = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11,...}$ denote the set of all primes less than $2^{100}$. Show that 
$$\sum_{p\in P} \frac{1}{p} < 8$$

I've looked through some articles about prime numbers to approach this, for example I tried using the fact that the average gap between consecutive prime numbers among the first $N$ integers is roughly $\log(N)$. However, I'm still not quite sure how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: major theorem due to Mertens. In Hardy and Wright, for example.

Comment: Hardy and Wright, Theorem 427, page 351 in the fifth edition. Constant $B_1 \approx 0.261497,$   for primes up to $x$, sum of prime reciprocals is $B_1 + \log \log x + o(1),$  natural logs. For your problem you need a size bound on the error term

Comment: Given that $\ln \ln 2^{100} + M \approx 4.5$, maybe there is another approach to bound this ?

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$
\frac x{\log x-1}\lt\pi(x)\lt\frac x{\log x-1.1}
$$

for $x\ge60184$ (inequality $(6.6)$ in [Estimates of Some Functions Over Primes without R.H.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) by Pierre Dusart), and thus

$$
\pi\left(2^k\right)-\pi\left(2^{k-1}\right)\lt\frac{2^k}{k\log2-1.1}-\frac{2^{k-1}}{(k-1)\log2-1}\;,
$$

so the sum of the reciprocals of the primes between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k$ is bounded above by

$$
\frac2{k\log2-1.1}-\frac1{(k-1)\log2-1}\lt\frac2{(k-2)\log2}-\frac1{(k-2)\log2}=\frac1{(k-2)\log2}\;.
$$

Summing this for $k=17$ to $100$ yields

$$
\sum_{k=17}^{100}\frac1{(k-2)\log2}=\frac{H_{98}-H_{14}}{\log2}\lesssim2.77\;,
$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). We can readily sum the reciprocals of the remaining primes from $1$ to $2^{16}$; here’s [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org) code for that:

```
j = var('j')
P=Primes()
sum ([1/P.unrank(j) for j in [0..6542]]).numerical_approx()
```

The result is

$$
\sum_{p\lt2^{16}}\frac1p\lesssim2.67\;,
$$

so in total the reciprocals of the primes up to $2^{100}$ sum to less than $2.77+2.67=5.44$.